# Why does PyCharm think that this variable may be referenced before assignment while True loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I have the following method that makes a HTTP GET request. I have added some error handling to it to ensure that it does not return a response unless there have been no network errors.

When the method is as follows Pycharm does **not** think that the `response` variable may be referenced before assignment:

```
    def requests_with_error_handling(self, url):
        while True:
            try:
                response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=random_proxy())
                break
            except Exception as e:
                self.pretty_print(e)
                time.sleep(1)               
        return response
```

However, when I add a `continue` statement at the bottom of the `except` block PyCharm does not like it and says that the `response` variable may be referenced before assignment, even though I believe both code blocks do the exact same thing and the `continue` statement is unnecessary since the the execution will move to the top of the `while` loop anyway if the `continue` is not present.

```
    def requests_with_error_handling(self, url):
        while True:
            try:
                response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=random_proxy())
                break
            except Exception as e:
                self.pretty_print(e)
                time.sleep(1)
                continue
        return response
```

Is this a bug with Pycharm or is my understanding of the program's control flow in Python incorrect?

Comment: What's your intention with using `continue` there anyway?

Comment: OP wants to retry the same request over and over until a valid response is returned ... of coarse since the call to requests.get doesnt change there is a significant chance it will forever just be in the stuck loop

Comment: Sure, but it'll retry that request even without the `continue`.

Answer (score 0):

all its effectively saying is that that variable is not guaranteed to exist within the scope it is returning at

In theory your loops should handle it... you could resolve it by adding response=None before the loop, that way the variable is guaranteed to be present in the scope of the return statement

as to your question, its neither a bug in pycharm nor is it you misunderstanding the control flow